# SQL Server group, filter and merge columns to show just one row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table that grows vertically with properties. I am using PIVOT to convert the rows values into columns and get required data. Now, I am trying to concatenate the values stored in two separate rows based on some filter. After concatenation, I just need to show one row out of this group and second row's id column should go as new column in the resultset.

I have a sample database table and a query that I have worked on:

**Source table:**

```
id  name
1   weight
2   height
3   bp-systolic
4   bp-diastolic
5   ABI
6   Notes
7   bp-systolic
8   bp-diastolic
```

**Properties table:**

```
id  propertykey propertyvalue   
1   value       200
1   unit        lbs
1   ExtId       7
2   value       74
2   unit        in
2   ExtId       8
3   value       120
3   unit        mm[Hg]
3   ExtId       9
4   value       80
4   unit        mm[Hg]
4   ExtId       9
7   value       126
7   unit        mm[Hg]
7   ExtId       10
8   value       87
8   unit        mm[Hg]
8   ExtId       10
```

Now with my query, I am able to join the two tables to get the rows into column like this:

```
id  name            desc        ExtId   related_id
1   weight          200 lbs     7   
2   height          74 in       8   
3   bp-systolic     120 mm[Hg]  9   
4   bp-diastolic    80 mm[Hg]   9   
7   bp-systolic     126 mm[Hg]  10  
8   bp-diastolic    87 mm[Hg]   10
```

I used the following query:

```
select  
    id,
    name,
    value + ' ' + unit [desc],
    '' as related_id
from (
        select s.ID, s.name, p.propertykey, p.propertyvalue from source S
        inner join properties P on s.ID = P.ID
        where s.name in ('height', 'weight', 'bp-systolic', 'bp-diastolic')

) as P
PIVOT (MAX([PropertyValue]) FOR [PropertyKey] IN ([Value], [Unit], [ExtId])) AS PT
```

How can I combine/merge the data for 'bp-systolic' and 'bp-diastolic' having the same "ExtId" and show one row like this:

```
id  name            desc        related_id
1   weight          200 lbs 
2   height          74 in   
3   bp-systolic     120/80          4
7   bp-systolic     126/87          8
```

Note, that related_id gets the "id" column from the 'bp-diastolic' since they are related based on "ExtId".

Here is my test database tables:

```
create table source (id int, name varchar(30))
create table properties (id int, propertykey varchar(30), propertyvalue varchar(30))

insert into source values (1, 'weight')
insert into source values (2, 'height')
insert into source values (3, 'bp-systolic')
insert into source values (4, 'bp-diastolic')
insert into source values (5, 'ABI')
insert into source values (6, 'notes')

insert into properties values (1, 'value', '200')
insert into properties values (1, 'unit', 'lbs')
insert into properties values (1, 'ExtId', '7')
insert into properties values (2, 'value', '74')
insert into properties values (2, 'unit', 'in')
insert into properties values (2, 'ExtId', '8')
insert into properties values (3, 'value', '120')
insert into properties values (3, 'unit', 'mm[Hg]')
insert into properties values (3, 'ExtId', '9')    
insert into properties values (4, 'value', '80')
insert into properties values (4, 'unit', 'mm[Hg]')
insert into properties values (4, 'ExtId', '9')
insert into properties values (5, 'value', '123')
insert into properties values (6, 'value', 'this is a sample note')
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using this type of design but I see a few flaws in your current implementation.  How do you know that `120/80` and `126/87` belong together? At this point, there is no way to tie these two records to the same row.

Comment: @bluefeet: Actually there *is* a way: you could `row_number` them partitioning by `name` and ordering by `id`. But I agree, the entire design could use some simplification.

Comment: @AndriyM The problem is what if the data was not entered in the same order. The current design assumes it will alway be entered in the correct way and you cannot rely on that.

Comment: @bluefeet, I agree this is not the cleanest design but this what I have to live at this time. Regarding your concern on how do we know they are together is by "ExtID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert your results from your pivot into a temp table then do a self join so that you get the id and values that you want. So assuming the table was named `#measures` you could do:

```
create table #measures(id int, name varchar(50), value varchar(1000), extId varchar(3));

insert into #measures
(id, name)
select id, name from source;

update m
  set extid = ext.propertyvalue
from #measures m
join properties ext on m.id = ext.id
  and ext.propertykey = 'extid';

update m
  set value = nm.propertyvalue
from #measures m
join properties nm on m.id = nm.id
  and nm.propertykey = 'value';

update m
  set value = value + ' ' + nm.propertyvalue
from #measures m
join properties nm on m.id = nm.id
  and nm.propertykey = 'unit';


        SELECT prim.ExtId, 
                prim.id,
                CASE WHEN dias.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'blood pressure' ELSE prim.name END AS measure,
                CASE WHEN dias.id IS NOT NULL THEN prim.[value] + '/' + dias.[value] ELSE prim.[value] END AS [desc],
                dias.id AS related_id
            FROM #measures prim
            LEFT JOIN #measures dias
                ON prim.ExtId = dias.ExtId
                AND prim.name = 'bp-systolic'
                AND dias.[name] = 'bp-diastolic'
            WHERE prim.name <> 'bp-diastolic'
```

EDIT: I've revamped this considerably given the comments below. Example can also be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ced9c/4

Comment: You're looking up the diastolic, but you still have to `group by` or `pivot`

Comment: @Andomar The presumption in the answer above is that one would use the results from the PIVOT done above in the question, then take that result and join above. Unless I've misunderstood the question, once the pivot is done, all that needs to be done after the pivot above is to join the two values together.

Comment: Yes, I was doing the PIVOT and it will make the query simpler. I am trying to get the query work now and see if it satisfies the result.

Comment: Jason, I feel that we missed "ExtId" column, that actually identifies the group for "BP". When there are more than one "BP" related data, we have to show both based on "ExtID". I have updated the test data that makes this query fail.

Comment: @kuul13 That's actually very helpful, because it gives a way to connect your data more directly. So in order for this to work, you'd also need to pull the ExtId in your pivot, as probably the first column, and then join on that ExtId. I'll update to reflect. Let me know if that helps your results.

Comment: Actually Jason, I have ExtID in my PIVOT and in the temp table.

Comment: @kuul13 Good point. You wouldn't want to take the max if your ids are the same, but I would think that if your source ids were the same, it wouldn't matter. In any case, I've got a safer version in the answer at this point. I'm not making the results null safe above...the presumption is that if you have a unit or a value entry that their propertyvalue won't be NULL. Easy to handle if so, though.

Comment: Jason, your solution helped me in creating a brilliant solution. All THANKS to your help with the query and sqlfiddle. I was having all the required information in my temp table, I just had to use your main query. Very well done!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can, change the design to non-[EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) alternative. A table with columns `weight, height, bp-diastolic, bp-systolic` would make the query a ton simpler.  The fact that weight is stored in LBS doesn't have to be stored in the database.  It would be up to the front-end to display/edit the weight in a metric chosen by the end-user.

Back to the question, within EAV you can look up the matching row like:

```
select  s.id
,       case when s.id = 3 then 'bloodpressure' else s.name end as name
,       max(case when p1.propertykey = 'value' then p1.propertyvalue end) +
        max(isnull('/' + p2.propertyvalue,'')) + 
        max(case when p1.propertykey = 'unit' then p1.propertyvalue end) as [desc]
,       max(p2.id) as related_id
from    source s
join    properties p1
on      s.id = p1.id
left join
        properties p2
on      p2.propertykey = 'value'
        and p2.id = 4 -- 4:bp-diastolic
        and p1.id = 3 -- 3:bp-systolic
where   s.id in (1,2,3) -- 1:weight, 2:height, 3:bp-systolic
group by
        s.id
,       s.name
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05ec2/4/0)

Comment: I am not in the position to change this design. It is being used by many other systems/modules. You solution seems interesting, I need to see how can I change the hardcoded Ids to names (weight, height) in properties tables that you have in you self join.